# I don't know what I did wrong in SGD Method

Tags: python

I have SGD Method:

```py
def StochasticgradientDescent(theta, alpha, num_observations, iterations):

    for i in range (iterations):
        x1 = random.choice(x)
        y1 = random.choice(y)
        f = np.matmul(x1,theta)
        error = np.subtract(f,y1)
        gradient = np.matmul(x1.transpose().reshape(2,1),error).reshape(2,1)
        theta = theta - (alpha  * gradient)
        
       
    return theta
```

and BGD method:

```py
def BatchgradientDescent(x, y, theta, alpha, num_observations, iterations):
    
    
    for i in range (iterations):
        
        f = np.matmul(x,theta)
        error = np.subtract(f,y)
        gradient = np.matmul(x.transpose(),error)
        theta = theta - (alpha * (1/num_observations) * gradient)
        
    return theta
```

I should get with SGD the same as with BGD:
[image: I should get the same as BGD]

I wonder what I did wrong in this SGD Method, the theta returned is different from what I got from normal equation and BGD... I feel the only difference between BGD and SGD is that SGD takes random point every iteration right? That's what I did in my code.. Please let me know what I did wrong.

Comment: Can you please provide more information.  At least, you should supply the inputs you're giving it, the output you're getting, and what you think the output should be.

Comment: If you work with random generators and expect the same result, you may [initialize random generator](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/index.html) always with the same seed.

Comment: Without knowing `x` and `y`, it is not possible to tell whether you have one or more local minima.

Comment: I will post the data given.

Comment: wait a minute.. I am not asked to find optimized point... I am asked to find optimal parameter for the dataset... It's a linear line, I am asked to find the optimal parameter using GD technique.

Comment: As @Heikki mentioned, it is possible that SGD and BGD return different minima's. (optimal parameters). Perhaps you could just run SGD multiple times and list out the results and logically speaking you should find the BGD result in on of the SGD's results.

Comment: @Sheldon_Zhang, it is necessary to make same `random.choice` for `x1` and `y1` in SGD. Running `random.choice` first for `x` and then separately for `y` will produce different rows chosen for `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to make same `random.choice` for `x1` and `y1` in SGD. See below the commented lines:

```
import numpy as np
import random

def StochasticGradientDescent(x, y, theta, alpha, num_observations, iterations):

    for i in range (iterations):
        xy1 = random.choice(np.concatenate((x,y),axis=1))  # same choice for x1 and y1
        x1 = xy1[:-1]                                      # separate x1
        y1 = xy1[-1]                                       # separate y1
        f = np.matmul(x1,theta)
        error = np.subtract(f,y1)
        gradient = np.matmul(x1.transpose().reshape(2,1),error).reshape(2,1)
        theta = theta - (alpha  * gradient)
        
    return theta

def BatchGradientDescent(x, y, theta, alpha, num_observations, iterations):
    
    for i in range (iterations):
        
        f = np.matmul(x,theta)
        error = np.subtract(f,y)
        gradient = np.matmul(x.transpose(),error)
        theta = theta - (alpha * (1/num_observations) * gradient)
        
    return theta

x = np.array([[2*a*a/500,10+a] for a in range(-500,499,10)])/1200
y = np.array([[a for a in range(-500,499,10)]]).transpose()/2000

theta1 = np.random.randn(2,1)
theta = BatchGradientDescent(x,y,theta1,0.01,x.shape[0],25000)
print(theta)

theta1 = np.random.randn(2,1)
theta = StochasticGradientDescent(x,y,theta1,0.01,x.shape[0],25000)
print(theta)
```

After such change, both SGD and BGD will yield similar results:

```
[[-0.01      ]
 [ 0.59943995]]
[[-0.00986322]
 [ 0.59945512]]
```